# How can i make PlayerGui Code run on a server script?

Tags: lua, roblox

I am making a game for fun and i want to make a gui that EVERYONE sees, not just me so how do i make EVERYONE see a gui, and not just the local player?

```lua
local Player = game:GetService('Players')
local player = Player.LocalPlayer
magic = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.DramaticOPMODE.Top1
magic2 = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.DramaticOPMODE.Top2
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    magic.Position = UDim2.new(0, 0, -1, 0)
    magic2.Position = UDim2.new(0, 0, 2, 0)
    magic2.Indicator.Visible = false 
    magic2.Indicator.Text = "" 
    magic:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(0, 0, 0, 0)) 
    magic2:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(0, 0, 0.748, 0))
    magic2.Indicator.Visible = true 
    wait(3)
```

i think this is enough code to get the point

Comment: Heyo, please edit your question and share a text version of your code. It makes it much easier for us to work with it when it's text.

Comment: its painful to do that.....

Comment: but ill try....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GUI code always needs to run in a LocalScript, because they execute on each individual client. But, if you want everyone to see something at the same time, you can use a server Script to fire a signal to all players that they should show the GUI, and you can do that using [RemoteEvents](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/RemoteEvent).

RemoteEvents allow communication between the server and clients, and vice versa. So if you want a player to press a button on their GUI, and have everyone see a thing happen, you need the client to fire the remote event up to the server, then have the server fire the event out to all players.

So, follow these steps...

1. Create a RemoteEvent in a shared location like ReplicatedStorage, or the Workspace
2. Create a Script in ServerScriptService or the Workspace that observers and fires the event.
3. Update your LocalScript to also observe the event, and play the animation when it happens.

So in your LocalScript...

```lua
-- find the RemoteEvent
local showTheMagicEvent = game.ReplicatedStorage.RemoteEvent -- whatever you named it
-- listen for when the server tells us that someone hit the button 
showTheMagicEvent.OnClientEvent:Connect(function()
    -- play the animation
    local magic = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.DramaticOPMODE.Top1
    local magic2 = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.DramaticOPMODE.Top2

    magic.Position = UDim2.new(0, 0, -1, 0)
    magic2.Position = UDim2.new(0, 0, 2, 0)
    magic2.Indicator.Visible = false 
    magic2.Indicator.Text = "" 
    magic:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(0, 0, 0, 0)) 
    magic2:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(0, 0, 0.748, 0))
    magic2.Indicator.Visible = true 
    wait(3)
    --...
end)


-- whenever someone hits this button, tell the server to show everyone
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    showTheMagicEvent:FireServer()
end
```

Then in your server Script...

```lua
-- find the RemoteEvent
local showTheMagicEvent = game.ReplicatedStorage.RemoteEvent -- whatever you named it
showTheMagicEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player)
    -- when this event fires on the server, turn around and fire it back to all the clients
    showTheMagicEvent:FireAllClients()
end)
```

Comment: Thank you, i am VERY new to lua and programming at all and don't understand much, it is very nice of you to help me.

Comment: I also fixed some mistakes you made, as the click indicator that fired server, it worked yes but it happened on run of the game so I somehow fixed it but your code overall worked.

Comment: Actually, Its alot easier to do! all you need to do is put a "FireServer()" thing in to the click, in the server do FireAllClients() and then in a **seperate** script you put onClientEvent()

Comment: Just for clarity, you mean a separate LocalScript right? The OnClientEvent must be processed in a LocalScript. I added the handler into the same LocalScript just for simplicity

Comment: absolutely it worked